# Check if string "starts with" another string

Tags: vbscript

I want to check if an address starts with http://www.youtube.com.

If I have something like this

```
if rs("mainVideoName")="http://www.youtube.com*" then
```

This doesn't work, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
 Function UrlStartsWith(string1, string2)
     UrlStartsWith = InStr(1, string1, string2, 1) = 1
 End Function

 If UrlStartsWith(rs("mainVideoName"), "http://www.youtube.com") Then


 End If
```

Starts with is tested by using `IntStr` and ensuring that it returns 1 as the starting position that the search string is found.  Since you are testing a URL the code above uses a TextCompare to make insensitive to case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `InStr()` function for this:

```
Dim positionOfMatchedString 
positionOfMatchedString= InStr(rs("mainVideoName"),"http://www.youtube.com")

If positionOfMatchedString > 0 Then
  // Do your stuff here
End If
```

As Anthony points out, this tells you that string2 is *contained* in string1. You could write it as:

```
If positionOfMatchedString = 1 Then
```

to check for it *beginning with*.

Comment: Strings are indexed from 1 in VB? :(

Comment: If string2 is not found, InStr returns 0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @JamieDixon: a) > 0 tests that string2 is _contained_ in string1 but not that string1 _startswith_ string2 (although considering the URL context _contains_ would likely be sufficient)  b) In VBScript you cannot Dimmension and assign a variable in a single statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder on the dimming. I figured a contains would suffice in this context as you rightly point out. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
Dim s: s = "http://www.youtube.com"
Dim l: l = Len(s)

If Left(rs("mainVideoName"), l) = s Then
    ' String begins with URL part '        
End If
```

Comment: I'd argue that a lowercase 'L' is a lousy name for a variable, especially when it's used in place of a number.  I had to look twice before I realized that you weren't just comparing the first letter of `rs("mainVideoName")`.

Answer (score 0):

mPersonally, I prefer using Left( over Instr(, however Instr( is a bit more powerful as the prefix's (http://, https://, www., etc...) become optional, however an extra step is necessary to test the found string's position within the searched string. And the above example is fine, but a bit obfuscated. I prefer clean, easy to read code, so here is my rendition:

```
Function StartsWith(searchString, keyWord)
    StartsWith = (left(searchString, len(keyWord)) = keyWord)
End Function
```

Use it like this

```
If StartsWith(rs("MainVideoName"), "https://www.youtube.com") Then
```